How to use SpaCy NER?
I am working on a mini-project to cluster similar sentences together. Before I can achieve that, I have to perform pre-processing to the extremely dirty data (these data are all user inputs, free text).
One of the pre-processing step that I thought of is to identify each sentence and classify it with a category. Even though it is free text, there are some key token per sentence such as "LOOK", "REPLACE", "CHECK".
To classify each sentences, I looked into NLP and discovered SpaCy. One of the component in SpaCy, NER, seems like the perfect task for this. I believe my use case is that I do not need to use the full SpaCy pipeline for this classification. I also understand that I need to add in my custom labels into the NER.
My question is - can I just add my custom label into SpaCy NER using add_label() and run the NER onto my dataset without the having to re-train the SpaCy model? My end goal is to simply classify the sentences into a category, based on the keywords.
This is quite unclear despite several days of researching.
Greatly appreciate any clarification on this. TIA.

For the task of clustering, you will have to generate embeddings of your sentences using any model available, a good starter model can be "sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2", it's small and is very good model for starters. About the task of preprocessing and category classification, can you share example sentences and estimated labels in the question.
Huggingface model link: https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2

Hi Ahmed. Some example of the sentences could be like Look for faulty PCI board in the PC or CPU fan need to be replaced or Look for faulty power supply, check and replace the component which in this case should label it into the three categories.

For the custom labels, you can add your labels but you must provide data with annotations for it to learn, otherwise your model simply won't even know what the labels mean. I'd suggest to follow the answer I've pasted below which is generally used for sentence similarity.

as far as I understand, you do not need to perform the classification task.
your primary goal is to cluster similar sentences, which can be done in 2 steps:

Generate embeddings for your dataset.
Apply some clustering
algorithm (kmeans, dbscan) etc.

Once this is done, you can provide a new sentence for inference, create its embeddings and find which cluster the new sentence is closest to (basically the clustering pipeline.

Hi Ahmed. I wouldn't be inputting my data into the model - I am just thinking of applying the NER and stop there, then apply another model using that dataset. If this is the case, is there a need to still train the spacy model?

I'm not sure if I get it correctly, but you are not going to train NER on your data, and you expect the model to classify sentences without training the model on your custom data. If this is what you expect, I don't think so it would work. For running NER on custom entities, you need to train it on custom data.

Hi Ahmed. SpaCy has a function called add_label() which allows you to add custom label into the existing model NER. This does not seem to require a re-training which is why my question is to ask whether I have to re-train the model after adding these custom labels. I am only interested to use the NER component to do categorising, and not the entire SpaCy pipeline.

Nopes you cannot. In simple words, when you use add_label, you need to train the NER for the new labels. You need to provide data with ground truth to let the model learn about new labels. You simply cannot use custom labels without training for it.

Hi Ahmed. Would Matcher() be the function to use in my use case then?
